# Fetching reminders using Swift Syntax

Tags: ios, swift, reminders, ekeventstore

I am trying to asynchronously fetch reminders (EKEntityTypeReminder) from EventKit. How do I write this in Swift?

```
[_store fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:predicate completion:^(NSArray *reminders) {
    for (EKReminder *reminder in reminders) {
        NSLog(@"Reminder %@",reminder);
    }
}];
```

… still struggling with adapting to the new Blocks/Closures syntax

Comment: What's tripping you up? What was your attempt?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
store.fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate(predicate) { reminders in
    for reminder in reminders {

    }
}
```

I prefer using [trailing closure syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_161)

Otherwise it could be...

```
store.fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate(predicate, completion: {(reminders: [AnyObject]!) -> Void in
    for reminder in reminders {

    }
})
```